# How to make TextChanged happen for copy/paste for TextBox in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

For silverlight control TextBox, when copy/paste content for TextBox Text property, TextChanged Event not happening.

How to make paste same as typing for Text in TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this.

I used the following XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbk" />
</StackPanel>
```

and the following event handler

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbk.Text += "X";
    }
```

Every time I typed in the TextBox or pasted text into it, the TextBlock gained another `X`.